# C# interface method declared in Base class need not be again implemented in Derived class

Tags: c#, .net, oop, c#-4.0

It could be a silly question, but I am learning, and I was just curious what's happening, today I was playing with few oops concepts and learning it in VS. I was again puzzled to see that we don't have to implement multiple interfaces same method into a derived class where ACTUALLY we "inherit" the interface, but in base class.

May I know how it works? My concern is, even though I do not "inherit" interface methods in base class, I use a method with same name. I also do not implement it in derived class.

Can somebody help me understand what's happening and how and why?

```
Class A
{
    public void Display()
    {
        Console.Writeline("I am from A");
    }
}

interface IA
{
    void Display();
}

interface IB
{
    void Display();
}

Class B : A, IA, IB
{

}

Class Final
{
    static void Main()
    {
        B b = new B();
        b.Display(); // displays class A Display method.
        Console.Readline();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you make `A` implement `IA` then `B` would only need to implement `IB` - it's called [inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx).

Comment: @James: But I am not implementing anything in A as in from the interface using ": IA or IB". That's why I am puzzled.

Comment: I think the question is more that `A` doesn't implement the interface - it just has a coincidentally-named method - so why is `B` considered to have implemented the interface. It's an interesting edge case I've not come across before, though really it's just a design decision for the compiler as to whether it should work (and intuitively, I'd say it should).

Comment: @Divine It doesn't matter, an interface is *contract* and as long as the concrete class *matches* the contract it will work.

Comment: @DanPuzey I see no edge case here? `B` inherits `A` which means it inherits the `Display` method which means when `Display` is called on `B` it hits the method in `A`.

Comment: @DanPuzey: Exactly. I wasn't writing it clearly in English. Yes, what you wrote is exactly what I wanted to convey and seek an understanding. Thank you so much.

Comment: I was going to post an answer, but it's just a quote of section 13.4.4 of the C# language spec (v 5). Key quote: "The implementation of a particular interface member I.M, where I is the interface in which the member M is declared, is determined by examining each class or struct S, starting with C and repeating for each successive base class of C, until a match is located"

Comment: @James: I meant that it's an edge case that an interface would be implemented in this way - that is, you won't see much production code where an interface's implementation is in the base class, but the base class doesn't explicitly include the interface too.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Thank you, I will take a look at specs too. Well still few questions lingering on my mind for learning. Thank you again.

Comment: @DanPuzey: +1 for Dan Puzzey. Exactly what is lingering in my mind and curious. Thank you Dan, I am just reading your explanation below.

Comment: @DanPuzey I wouldn't consider it an edge case I would consider it bad design, if `IA` is only really implemented by `A` (even though it's inherited by `B`) then `IA` should really be explicitly implemented by `A` then `IA` would be inherited along with `A` naturally. Of course, sometimes we don't always have control over the codebase so sometimes we need to make sacrafices...

Comment: @James: totally agree - I can't think of a reason that you'd design your own code to work like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I can't speak for the language team, you can answer this question by posing the alternative solution.

You want to know why `B` is considered to implement the interface `IA` even though the required method definition is in base class `A`, which doesn't implement the interface. So, let's consider the opposite: `B` should *not* be considered to implement the interface because the base class' method wasn't written with that interface in mind.

This means that your code doesn't compile. Why doesn't it compile? Because `B` doesn't implement required member `Display` of interface `IA`.

To fix this, you'd add a method `Display` to class `B`. That fixes the interface implementation. However, you now have a new compilation problem: you'll see a warning "B.Display()' hides inherited member 'ConsoleApplication1.A.Display()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended."

This is because your `A.Display` wasn't overrideable - and you don't want to override it. You can implement a method to call `base.Display()` if you choose, but this is extra code to essentially do nothing, and it makes a mess of your inheritance since a `new` method is handled differently to an override. (If you write `A x = new B(); x.Display();` then you'll actually call `A.Display()` directly, which could get messy as your code evolves and is an accident waiting to happen.)

Alternatively, you might implement an entirely new `B.Display` method. What you've also now done is hidden the method implemented in class `A` from anyone who might derive from `B` or create an instance of `B`. Using `new` to hide methods is rarely a recipe for an understandable object structure, and this would be no exception - all so that you can implement an interface cleanly.

So ultimately, I would imagine, this decision was made because the alternative is far too messy.

Comment: Hi Dan, yes correct there's a lot to consider as you wrote. That gives me good insights. I just have one question, maybe silly question. So if I want to hide any method of an interface that is implemented in the derived class say B (Derived from A) using "new" and will I not be able to call it in C if C:B? (Which in turn derives from A, when I just wanted to have a new implementation in B and not in other derived classes say C, D and so on. Will I be able to access Base class A's method if I hide it in between the hierarchy?

Comment: If you hide it like that then the only way you can execute `A.Display` would be to reference your instance as a variable of type `A`. So, as I mentioned in the answer, if you declare `A thing = new C()` and then call `thing.Display()`, you will be calling `A`'s implementation. This is a horrendous code smell, though - really not recommended!

Comment: Dan, thank you so much, helps me to understand it well. Just practicing everything now :) :) Cheers

Answer (score 3):

The reason is because the implementation is "implied" -- an implicit implementation of an interface.

```
Class A
{
 public void Display()
 {
     Console.Writeline("I am from A");
 }
}

interface IA
{
 void Display();
}

interface IB
{
 void Display();
}

Class B : A, IA, IB
{
  void AI.Display() { Console.Writeline("I am from AI.Display"); }
}

Class Final
{
 static void Main()
 {
   B b = new B();
   b.Display(); // displays class A Display method.
   (b as IB).Display(); // displays class A Display method.
   (b as AI).Display(); // displays AI.Display
   Console.Readline();
 }
}
```

The above example now has an explicit implementation of the interface method display.  Notice the slight variation in the method signature -- this is how you declare an explicit implementation, that is used specifically when the object is represented by the interface, in this case `(b as AI)`.

Otherwise, if the method signature matches, it is used automatically (implicitly) as the method for the interface.

Comment: Eli, that is fine. But we do not explicitly mention it using ":IA or IB" in class A. There is no readability at all either. Just confuses me.

Comment: Which is why my first part of the answer defines that .NET implicitly uses the method as its interface implementation.  Only when you use an explicit implementation does it not.  The answer is how the language works.  If it confuses you, I'm sorry, but that is not a fault of my answer.  It's just how the language works!

Comment: Eli, thank you, that's a good insight, I will also understand such things more as I am learning :) Thank you so much for helping me. I appreciate it. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

What's happening in your situation is that class B is satisfying the IA interface contract through the fact that its inheriting the appropriate IA method implementations from class A.

Comment: Thank you pixel for the insights, that helps me :) Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The way to look at it is this - an interface is a *contract* (it has no implementation) therefore it simply demands that any implementing class defines all the same members which it defines in the contract.

In your case you have 1 method in your interface `Display`, your class `B` is the only class implementing this interface and it doesn't *explicitly* define an implementation for `Display` (perhaps this is where your confusion is). However, it is inheriting from `A` which *does* define an implementation for it therefore `B` implements the interface by default.

Comment: James thank you so much, that helps me understand, just doing few other reads and experiments to understand it better. Thank you so much :) :) Cheers